# bash: check if sqlite has schema and alter table

Tags: bash, sqlite

I have 2 working blocks of code.

The first checks, whether my sqlite3 DB has a particular schema

```
#!/bin/bash

if sqlite3 my.db <<< .schema | grep -qi 'create table my_data'; then
    echo "all good"
fi
```

The second ads two new columns to the existing DB

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlite3 my.db <<EOS
    ALTER TABLE my_data ADD col1 JSON DEFAULT "{}" NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE my_data ADD col2 REAL DEFAULT "0.0" NOT NULL;
EOS
```

Now I would like to combine them to

```
if schema exists
    add col1
    add col2
fi
```

but unfortunately, I don't get it running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if sqlite3 my.db ".schema my_data" | grep -q 'CREATE TABLE my_data'; then
    sqlite3 my.db "ALTER TABLE my_data ADD col1 JSON DEFAULT '{}' NOT NULL";
    sqlite3 my.db "ALTER TABLE my_data ADD col2 REAL DEFAULT 0.0 NOT NULL";
fi
```

ok, got faster to the solution myself :)